# Add text to Google Sheets Spreadsheet in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have experience with Google Apps Script and strong programming fundamentals, however I am very new to Android Development. I am trying to simply add text to a spreadsheet with a public URL from within Android Studio. I am looking for something like the `appendText` method in Google Apps Script Spreadsheet Service. I have seen some that use Google forms, but I want to stay away from that. As I am very new to this please include any and all imports that are required.

Answer (score 1):

There are two routes to connecting to apps script from Andriod.

You can connect to a Script published as a webapp.

> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Or use the execution API

> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/android

Comment: They both have working code.  This isn't the right site to get someone to write code for you.